# Make on a Raspberry Pi "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi, geany

I am working on a Raspberry Pi project whereby we need to program a robot to run by itself.

Currently I am using Geany as the Environment and C programming language. The steps are obtained from the following tutorial:

http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/getting-your-raspberry-pi-ready-for-c-programming

However because I have never done this before, I encountered a problem. The website says Geany requires a 'makefile' to execute the program.  I created a simple main.c and makefile

#### main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

#### makefile

```
CC=gcc                  
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS =                  

all: main.o 
    gcc main.o -o target_bin

main.o: main.c 
    gcc -I . -c main.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm target_bin
```

From Geany, I tried to Build/Compile/Make but I keep getting error like:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I tried compiling the `main.c` via command prompt, but it still prompts me with the same error:

> 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

In summary, I have no idea how to make a makefile. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: check here ,this would be helpful  http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: I know nothing about geany but it sounds like your path can't find "make" or "gcc".

Comment: @ Gangadhar

I looked through that website before. It doesn't mention where to run the "make" command. In Geany, from main.c I went Menu>Build>Make but it still gives me same error : "make" is not recognized...

Comment: @user2741620.. Which os you are using? Linux/Windows?

Comment: @  Sagar Sakre Windows 8

Comment: Please change the question (title, text, tags) to make it abundantly clear that you are working on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Execute `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the compiler and a bunch of other goodies. I would execute `sudo apt-get update` first to ensure your system is up to date.

For the GNU `make` docs:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Where do I execute that? In Command prompt? I navigated to the path where my main.c is and typed what you wrote, but it gave me error saying 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

All the above commands are in typed into what linux users know as terminal(for you windows guys, it's technically command prompt. What you need to learn in order to understand the suggestions given is how to create a telnet connection with your RPi device. As well as how to distinguish commands that are internet dependant such as apt-get. Sudo is a temporary root permission for the line of command to be typed out after sudo. I suggest exploring either ubuntus wiki or archs wiki. Get used to google and C.L.I.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write make file like this:

```
CC  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
LDFLAGS = 
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

TARGETS = main
#     

main:main.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

main.o:main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETS)
    rm -rf *.o
```

When you work with cross toolchains, you can just do this:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=your toolchains's prifix
```

then you can get the binary you want.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is  cross toolchains? When you asked me to do this, where do I do it?

Comment: cross toolchains just as gcc/g++ compile code for arm/misp/ppc etc hardware platform, but running on the host machine, if you do not need, you can just type make, that's enough.